# Can someone explain multiple refraction of light in certain structures in Huygen's wave front method?

Tags: optics

I'm a very visual learner and Huygen's treatise on light itself is very geometric in its analysis of this refraction.

I like consistency in theories and since Huygens used the idea of hemispherical partial waves to treat light's interaction with mediums, I wanted to try to understand the refraction of this crystal in those terms.

[image: Perpendicular light entering crystal]

In this example of a perpendicular wave of light, RC, I understand how the refraction occurs. NQ will leave the crystal in both the same direction to RC and parallel as well.

Where does the second wave of light come from?

edit: What I mean is, what other light wave can enter AB such that it is in the same direction as NQ(after it has left the crystal)?

Comment: a link to the source https://www.gutenberg.org/files/14725/14725-h/14725-h.htm

Comment: Page 63: “I had then less trouble after that in admitting two emissions of waves in one and the same body ... I removed this difficulty by regarding these particles as being of a very rare texture, or rather as composed of other much smaller particles, between which the ethereal matter passes quite freely.”

Comment: @HolgerFiedler So the ellipsoidal waves were due to the "ether" trapped within this crystal, letting the light move more freely in a certain direction. I still don't see why that would produce two wave fronts forming an image of double refraction.